# Copying boost::program_options::parsed_options

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

Consider this function:

```
po::parsed_options ParserClass::parseOptions(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return po::command_line_parser(argc, argv)
            .options(desc)
            .positional(pos)
            .run();
}
```

`desc` and `pos` are member variables of `ParserClass`.

Is this function safe or does it return a `parsed_options` object that has pointers pointing to released free store memory because the original object's allocated memory is released when the function returns?

How can you know the semantics? I tried to read the source code to find out but it was a little cryptic to me. The documentation doesn't seem to tell.

If the function is not safe, how could it be fixed? Should you extend the class and define a move operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the object can be copied or moved, it can basically mean three things:

1. The operations are well-defined and behave safely
2. Library authors have screwed up and copy/move is ill-behaved
3. You have to follow some non-obvious conventions while use using it (usually due to performance reasons).

With boost (and so widely-used parts of it as `program_options`) we can rule out second option, and for the third one you may consult the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/basic_command_line_parser.html) to see that there is nothing ridiculous there.

If you really want to know that `argv` pointer is not escaping the function (I guess it is the only suspicious place there), you can check that the corresponding `basic_command_line_parser` constructor copies it into a vector of `std::string`s (via `detail::make_vector`:)

```
template<class charT>
basic_command_line_parser<charT>::
basic_command_line_parser(int argc, const charT* const argv[])
: detail::cmdline(
    // Explicit template arguments are required by gcc 3.3.1 
    // (at least mingw version), and do no harm on other compilers.
    to_internal(detail::make_vector<charT, const charT* const*>(argv+1, argv+argc+!argc))),
    m_desc()
{}
```